# ActiveJDBC in a big project

Tags: hibernate, activejdbc

I am using old good Hibernate and reading about news int ORM area. ActiveJDBC seems to be quite new ORM, does anybody use it in a big project? Where Hibernate is stronger and why? What ActiveJDBC is misisng?
 Does it for example have L1 cache and cooperates with Spring inside Spring -managed transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm the author of ActiveJDBC and other [JavaLite](http://javalite.io/) projects. ActiveJDBC is a newer than Hibernate, but has been around since 2009. AJ is not a rewrite of Hibernate, but a different ORM implementation based on [Active Record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern), largely inspired by Ruby on Rails. I personally used it on a number of large projects for Sears, Humana, Groupon, Edovo, Discover Health. It is not as commonly used as Hibernate, but there are quite a few well-known companies that use it: GoDaddy, Amazon, Yahoo, Ebay and others.

ActiveJDBC is stronger than Hibernate in web applications, where you do not need to keep a graph of objects, and every instance of a model (entity) is like a map, that is simply passed to a view. This vastly simplifies coding and reduces about 80% of code compared to Hibernate. ActiveJDBC is on average is 50% faster than Hibernate at runtime.

ActiveJDBC uses a [Pass-Through Model](http://javalite.io/pass_through_framework), which is also completely different from Hibernate  object graph model. Hibernate was designed at the time of client-server, AJ was designed at the time of web apps and APIs.

L1 Caching is specific to Hibernate. ActiveJDBC has a [different caching model](http://javalite.io/caching). ActiveJDBC has no "session". Every model is responsible for itself. For more information, refer to [documentation](http://javalite.io/documentation).